# Specflow Generate Step Definition is missing from the context menu

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013, specflow

I right click on my feature file I should get the option to Generate step definitions.  It is not there in the context menu.
I did a search and it says to install specrun for nunit.
I tried installing SpecRun.Nunit from Manage NuGet Packages.

I get the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to load the service index for source 
http://packagesource.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'packagesource'          0
```

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 isntalled.
I have installed Selenium-webdriver, Specflow

How can I solve this issue please, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the specflow nuget package as well as the Visual Studio integration package from the menu item Tools -> "Extensions and Updates..."

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have to do to make the option appear in the context menu in VS2019.

1. I installed Specflow normally, from Extensions-> Manage Extensions,
   then searched for Specflow for Visual Studio 2019.
2. Installed the package and re-started VS.
3. Then I created a new project, a C# Test.
4. Once the initial setup is ready, from the context menu in the
   Solution Explorer I went "Add->New Item..." and selected "SpecFlow
   Feature File", I typed in the info I wanted in my Feature file.
5. Over any of the Gherkin lines, I right clicked to get the context
   menu and selected "Go to Definition". A dialog displays, telling me
   that there is not a match, but I can save the lines in clipboard. I
   selected Yes.
6. Then again on the Solution Explorer (like step 4), Right Click
   "Add->New Item...", but now selected "SpecFlow Step Definition". The
   Step Definition will be that for the calculator test.

**Now here's the trick:**

- Delete all of the steps, leaving the main class empty.

Like this:

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace SpecflowFirst
{
    [Binding]
    public class SpecFlowFeature1Steps
    {

    }
}
```

- Then paste the snippet you got from the dialog box inside the main
  class

Like this:

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace SpecflowFirst
{
    [Binding]
    public class SpecFlowFeature1Steps
    {
        [Given(@"I navigated to the github login page")]
        public void GivenINavigatedToTheGithubLoginPage()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
    }
}
```

This will trigger errors in the compilation. If you point to the error in "ScenarioContext" and do "Show potential fixes", one of the fixes will be to install "Sprecflow extension". With this you install the remaining integration that will now display the option in the context menu.

That fixed the issue to me and now I can see in the context menu "Generate Step Definitions"

Answer (score 0):

I followed Kyon's excellent walkthrough, but this didn't work for me.  Even though SpecFlow was installed correctly, it didn't recognise the following library, or make any suggestions to "Fix this issue":

```
using TechTalk.Specflow
```

Then I noticed that, with the a brand-new MsTest project and the latest VS2019 (as of October 2020) you need to install a slightly-*earlier* version of SpecFlow (v2.1 compared to v2.4).

So, if you're also having problems getting this illusive "Generate Step Definitions" menu item to appear, check out your Dependencies\Packages for any exclamation marks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Generate Step Definitions" has changed to "Define Steps..." in Visual Studio 2022. Open the feature file->right click anywhere inside file->Define Steps